# Can any ally benefit from the help action during a combat turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, actions, advantage-and-disadvantage, helping

Party members Alex, Bart, and Caroline are in combat with a Drow, in that turn order (A, B, C, D).

Alex uses the help action on the Drow, being within 5ft.  If Bart chooses not to attack on her turn, can Caroline attack with advantage because of Help?  If Bart decided to attack, would Bart have gotten advantage instead?

Does a specific ally need to be named to benefit from the advantage?  Or is it first-to-attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

**[Help](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Help)**

> You can lend your aid to another creature in the completion of a task. When you take the Help action, the creature you aid gains advantage on the next ability check it makes to perform the task you are helping with, provided that it makes the check before the start of your next turn.
>
> Alternatively, **you can aid a friendly creature** in attacking a creature within 5 feet of you. You feint, distract the target, or in some other way team up to make your ally's attack more effective. If your ally attacks the target before your next turn, the first attack roll is made with advantage.

The Help action works on your (designated) ally, not on the target.